# VBA Import CSV file to excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have an VBA code to import CSV file (35 columns, 80 rows) into Excel, it worked well at the beginning but it don't work for certain files. Where is the problem in my code?

```
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim Arr

    Set Wb = GetObject(Application.GetOpenFilename("csv file,*.csv", , "please choose a csv file", , False))
    Arr = Wb.ActiveSheet.Range("A12").CurrentRegion
    Wb.Close False
    Range("A12").Resize(UBound(Arr), UBound(Arr, 2)) = Arr
```

Comment: What happens when you try to use it?  How does it fail?

Comment: If **A12** is isolated, then `CurrentRegion` will be a single cell and `Arr` will not be an array and the `Resize` will fail.

Comment: It must be this error. How can I correct it plz?